# How to get readable text from html block

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

```
region = input("Insert region of search ").lower()

#Get region of the world for language

first_name , last_name = input("").split()

#Get first and last name of person of interest or object

res = requests.get("https://"+ region + ".wikipedia.org/wiki/" + first_name + "_" + last_name)

#get Wiki page of person/object

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

#Parse in html

infobox = (soup.select("img")[:4])

#Get the first 4 images

content = (soup.select("p")[0])

#Get the first block of text

for info in range(len(infobox)):
    link = infobox[info].get("src")
    if first_name in link:

        urllib.request.urlretrieve("http:" + link, "sample.png")

        img = Image.open("sample.png")
        img.show()
        break

#Loop through images until it finds the one about the person/object
```

So I made this small program, that basically brings back the picture of what you search for - I'm sure it can be improved, if you have any feedback/tips - but I also want to get the first block of text from the wiki article - I am able to get the block of html text, but I do I remove the `<p>` and `<b>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, you just have to put ".text" in the content